# Can I add single property to context with annotation?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I can add multiple properties with

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan
public class StarterAppConfig {
}
```

Can I add explicitly one or several properties directly from annotations?

Like this:

```
@Configuration
@Property("user", "myuser")
@Property("password", "mypassword")
@ComponentScan
public class StarterAppConfig {
}
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

So, I was to write [my own annotation `SingleProperty`](https://github.com/dims12/DesktopIoC/blob/master/ChildContext/src/main/java/childcontext/SingleProperty.java) and [own processing for it](https://github.com/dims12/DesktopIoC/blob/master/ChildContext/src/main/java/childcontext/ChildContextFactory.java#L73).

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but can I ask you why you want to do this ?

Comment: See my update, it refers the project. In short I would like to specify `FXML` path in properties of child context, but to avoid boilerplate.

Comment: @Dims, if you found the answer to your question yourself, you should post it as answer instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Value` and set a default value for a property, see the examples here: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-value-default-value/

Answer (score 0):

You can use do this in your main class

```
Map<String,Object> defaultProperties = new HashMap<>();
defaultProperties.put("user", "myuser");

SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties(defaultProperties)
```

JavaDoc : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#setDefaultProperties-java.util.Map-